# Trying to optimize my background changes, and trying to make them fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just about finished my Weather Forecast page for my FCC challenge. I don't like how the code for swapping my bg works however. Feels wrong, but for the life of me I can't work out how to fix it. At the same time, it means I can't find a good way to make the bg fade in instead of flicking into existence. Any ideas?

https://codepen.io/EpicTriffid/pen/xrjxVE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var curUnit = "F";
  
  //Backgrounds
  
  var clearday = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/125457/pexels-photo-125457.jpeg')";
  var clearnight = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/355465/pexels-photo-355465.jpeg')";
  var rain = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/125510/pexels-photo-125510.jpeg')";
  var snow = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/41088/pexels-photo-41088.jpeg')";
  var sleet = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/27629/pexels-photo-27629.jpg')";
  var wind = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/6041/nature-grain-moving-cereal.jpg')";
  var fog = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/109037/pexels-photo-109037.jpeg')";
  var cloudy = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/158163/clouds-cloudporn-weather-lookup-158163.jpeg')";
  var partlycloudyday = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/152536/pexels-photo-152536.jpeg')";
  var partlycloudynight = "url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/23985/pexels-photo-23985.jpg')";
  
  
  //location API
  
  var darksky = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.darksky.net/forecast/';
  
  var apikey = "15f8bf5641489ec32f66662221933c14";
  
  $("#myweather").load("window",function() {     
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(loc) { 
          $("#location").load("window", function() {
              $("#location").html(loc.city).fadeIn(1000);
          });
          
          //Weather Summary
          
          $("#result").load("window", function() {
              $.getJSON(darksky + apikey + "/" + loc.latitude + "," + loc.longitude, function(forecast){
                $("#result").html(forecast.currently.summary).fadeIn(2000);
                
                //Skycon
                
                function addSkycon() {
                  var skycons = new Skycons({color: 'white'});
                  var skyconCanvas = document.getElementById("skycon");
                  skycons.add(skyconCanvas, forecast.currently.icon);
                  var iconsum = forecast.currently.icon
                  skycons.play();
                  $("#skycon").fadeIn(2000);
                  if(iconsum == "clear-day") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = clearday;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "clear-night") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = clearnight;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "rain") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = rain;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "snow") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = snow;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "sleet") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = sleet;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "wind") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = wind;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "fog") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = fog;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "cloudy") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = cloudy;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "partly-cloudy-day") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = partlycloudyday;
                  }
                  else if(iconsum == "partly-cloudy-night") {
                    document.body.style.backgroundImage = partlycloudynight;
                  }
                } addSkycon();
                
                //Temperature
                
                $("#corf").load("window", function() {
                  $("#corf").fadeIn(2000);
                });
                
                var ftemp = Math.round(forecast.currently.temperature);
                var ctemp = Math.round((forecast.currently.temperature - 32) *
                                       (5 / 9))
                $("#temp").html(ftemp).fadeIn(2000);
                $("#corf").on("click", function() {
                  $("#temp").fadeOut(function() {
                    if (curUnit == "F") {
                      $("#temp").html(Math.round(ctemp));
                      $("#degreeswitch").html("&degc"); 
                      curUnit = "C";
                    }
                    else {
                      $("#temp").html(Math.round(ftemp));
                      $("#degreeswitch").html("&degf");
                      curUnit = "F";
                    }
                    $("#temp").fadeIn(); 
                  });
                });
              });
          });
        }
      });
  });
});
```

```css
#spacer { 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:50px; 
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;  
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:black;
  background-image:
}
.text {
  color:white;
  font-family:"raleway";    
}
#myweather {
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-top:30px;
  font-size:5em;
}
#header {
  float:left;
  margin-left:20px;
}
#location {
  font-style: italic;
  color:white;
  margin-left:-200px;
  display:none;
}
#skycon {
  padding:30px;
  display:none;
}
#result {
  position:relative;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:60px;
  display:none;
}
#temp {
  padding-left:60px;
  font-size:150px;
  display:none;  
}
#corf {
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  display:none;
  margin-left:-45px;
  margin-top:-30px;
}
#degreeswitch {
  font-family:"raleway";
}
#degreecon {
  margin-top:2%; 
  margin-left:-2%;  
}
#mark {
  text-align: center;
  font-family:"raleway";
  font-size: 20px; 
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Fonts-->

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/climacons-fork/1.0.0/climacons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<!--Background-->

<!--Skycons-->

<script src="https://rawgithub.com/darkskyapp/skycons/master/skycons.js"></script>

<!--Header-->
<h1 id="myweather" class="text">myWeather.</h1>

<!-- location -->
<div id="header" class="container-fluid">
  <h4 class="text">Weather for :</h4>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h4 id="location" class="text"></h4>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <canvas id="skycon" width="300" height="300">
          </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <h2 class="text" id="result"></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <h1 class="text" id="temp"></h1>
    </div>
    <div id="degreecon" class="col-xs-2">
      <svg id="corf">
        <text id="degreeswitch" x="31" y="67" fill="white" font-size="50px">&degf</text>
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" stroke="white" stroke-width="3" fill="transparent"/>        
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mark">By<a href="https://codepen.io/EpicTriffid/full/MJzMgK/" target="_blank"> Epic Triffid </a>and powered by<a href="https://darksky.net/forecast/" target="_blank"> Darksky </a>and<a href="" target="_blank"> GeoIP</a></div>
```

Sorry, I also cant seem to get links to work :/

Comment: post your code here, edit the question and add it

Comment: Added code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it for you. Here is an updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwvELj

Basically, I've created a new element `<div id="background"></div>` and made it fixed covering full-screen. I set the `z-index` of it to 0 and wrapped the rest of the content inside `<div id="wrapper"></div>` and set that `z-index` to 1. I've changed your if statements and instead of directly modifying the `<body>` tag's CSS with a `background-image`, I'm now setting a variable to the URL of the image.

Now is when the magic is happening. Here's the snippet

```
var bg = new Image();
bg.onload = function(){
   $('#background').css({'background-image': 'url('+imgUrl+')'});
   $('#background').addClass('visible');
}
bg.src = imgUrl;
```

We're creating a new object of `Image` in JS and defining a function to be run when the image is loaded. The function sets the background image of `#background` and also adds a class `visible` to it. I've made the background invisible by default and set the class `visible` to give it `opacity: 1;`. This with a `1.5s` transition makes up for a nice fade in effect. Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: You are an absolute hero. Thankyou so much! So had i actually done anything wrong in the set up, or was it all good?

Comment: It was all good, and even better with a background fading in! @EpicTriffid